# My python code is placing digits by physical location, i.e 7 is greater than 45 because 7 is greater than 4.5

Tags: python

As I said in the title, my code is evaluating numbers in a bizarre way I've never encountered before and I can only assume I've made some basic mistake. It considers the first digit of a number against the first digit of any other number, whether or not that makes any sense. so 2 is greater than 1,000,000, because 2 is greater than 1.

```
print('Hello, please enter five integers, one by one.')

a = input("Enter an integer.")
b = input("Enter an integer.")
c = input("Enter an integer.")
d = input("Enter an integer.")
e = input("Enter an integer.")

#this asks for the user to input each integer

if a > b:
  maxint = a

else:
  maxint = b

if c > maxint:
  maxint = c

if d > maxint:
  maxint = d

if e > maxint:
  maxint = e

#these if statements determine the largest integer

if a < b:
  minint = a
else:
  minint = b

if c < minint:
  minint = c

if d < minint:
  minint = d

if e < minint:
  minint = e

#these if statements determine the smallest integer

a = float(a)
b = float(b)
c = float(c)
d = float(d)
e = float(e)

mean = (a + b + c + d + e)
mean = (mean / 5)

#this determines the average

print('Minimum: ',minint) 
print('Maximum: ',maxint)
print('Mean: ',mean)

#this prints the results
```

If I enter the following:

```
1
7
45
2
-2
```

it will display 7 as the maximum. This makes no sense to me.

Comment: You are not comparing `int`. You are actually comparing `str`. You need to cast your inputs to `int`. For example: `int(input("Enter an integer."))` for all of your inputs.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was something obvious.

Comment: If you are going to be dealing with decimals, might as well do `float` instead.

Comment: This is Python 3, right? It should be tagged as such...

Comment: FWIW, your commenting style is a bit odd. You have your comments describing each section of code after the code instead of before it. It's a bit misleading.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing `str` types not `int` types.

`str` types are sequences so they are compared one item at a time. The character `7` is larger than the character `4`. Therefore the `str(7) > str(45)` is `true`.

Look at the built in functions `min()` and `max()`. Your code could be simplified:

```
maxint = max(a, b, c, d, e)
minint = min(a, b, c, d, e)
```